# Faking the date for a specific shell session

Tags: linux, unix, shell, unix-shell, time

I'm certainly trying to achieve something weird here, but I want to fake the date locally for a shell session on GNU/Linux.
I need to black-box test how a program behaves at different dates, and modifying the system-wide date can have unwanted side effects (cron jobs, messed up logs, etc).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just use executable `faketime` (from ubuntu repositories `sudo apt-get install faketime`) by:

```
faketime -f "-15d" date
```

Or even fake time in whole shell by

```
faketime -f "-15d" bash -l
```

Comment: Kyle Brant posted pretty much this answer [back in 2010](http://serverfault.com/a/138371/58408). Please [edit] your answer to expand on it in some way that makes it substantially different from the existing answers.

Comment: My solution is much easier than using library preload as Kyle Brant answered because location of libfaketime .so file is very specific and depends on linux distribution and package managers.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This answer is not at all the same as Kyle Brant's.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This answer is significantly easier than Kyle Brant's.

Comment: I support this answer :-)

Answer (score 30):

Haven't tried this one out yet.  But if this is current is looks like someone already wrote the library you can preload with [libfaketime](http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/).

The basic usage is:

```
user@host> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="-15d" date
Mon Nov  8 12:01:12 CEST 2007
```

You can use `ltrace` to make sure all the time functions your application uses are covered.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the TZ variable to an oddball value.

```
$ date
Tue May  4 06:24:43 CDT 2010
$ date -u
Tue May  4 11:24:47 UTC 2010
$ export TZ='CDT-3:12'
$ date
Tue May  4 14:36:53 CDT 2010
$ export TZ='CDT+5:37'
$ date
Tue May  4 05:48:00 CDT 2010
```

Comment: Clever trick, but it only modifies the timezone, so this way you are limited to [-12 hours,+11 hours] range.

Comment: @nicoulaj
`date Thu Aug  9 12:12:50 CDT 2018`, ` TZ='UTC+120:00' date
Sat Aug  4 09:00:47 UTC 2018`, `TZ='UTC-120:00' date
Tue Aug 14 09:01:41 UTC 2018`. Roughly +- one week.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to preload a library that has an alternative `time()` implementation.

Comment: Depending on how the program(s) access current time, you might have to preload alternative implementations of gettimeofday, clock_gettime, and/or possibly others as well, but yes, I've used this approach with success before.

Comment: It's a Java program, and it seems to work well with libfaketime.

Answer (score 0):

[datefudge](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/datefudge.1.html) is an alternative to libfaketime.

It's used like so:

```
datefudge "2020-01-01 12:00" bash
```

to change the running shell to noon 1st of January 2020